# How to handle tabindex at complex form?

Tags: html

I need to use tabindex for accesing the fields. In the form there is two radio buttons, that enable one or other fields group. One of the fields in a group is a widget with a complex functionality implemented with javascript.

My form is something like this:

```
[ input 1 ]
[ input 2 ]

(radio button RB1) ---| <--|
                      |    |
[ input A1 ]          |    |
[ custom widget A2 ]  |    | 
----------------------|    | these radio buttons alternatively switch
                           | the inputs groups
                           | enabling/disabling the fields
                           |
(radio button RB2) ---| <--|
                      | 
[ input B1]           | 
[ input B2]           |
----------------------|
```

Possible flows:

```
[1][2] ----|
         (RB1) -> [A1][A2] 
           |
           |
         (RB2) -> [B1][B2]
```

How should I set tabindex attribute at each field?

Answer (score 2):

when using `tabindex` it is adviced to have a gap between each element so that you could inject elements to the form in the future. In you case, you should define the most prioritized.

So for you, you should add `tabindex` values to each of the input elements which replicate the priority you need. lowest value being the starting point.

[Tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/tabindex-html-attribute/) on adding tab indexes correctly.

For an example, say you need the checkboxes the most priority. Then you have to assign a low value to them. such as 1 and 2 which will make them the most prioritized elements in the page!

Comment: Which tabindex, do you think, should have each field in that diagram?

Comment: That depends on the requirement you have! see updated answer!